# too much recursion mixpanel jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixpanel

I'm experiencing problem with too much recursion when I'm sending event to MixPanel analytic. This is what I have:

```
onClick='_gaq.push([\"_setAccount\", \"UA-1111111-1\"]); _gaq.push([\"_trackEvent\", \"School\", \"Add School\"]);'
```

My onClick is in dynamically created <\li>. Thanks

Soulution:

Hi friends, this was one of those lame bugs. I had a JS file where I had MixPanel setup, after some time I've changed position of that setup to other file and I commented out old setup. For some reason that code was the problem, after I deleted it totally from file the problem was gone. If somebody know how to explain this it would be helpful? I hope that this will help somebody in a future.